# Extract sub-matrix based on conditions of specific columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-manipulation

I want to Select a sub-matrix `x7992` based on conditions of Certain columns of original `data` matrix. Specifically, the original matrix is 23166-by-9, follow a original Gauss code

```
x7992  =selif(data,data[.,col_coh].==0 .and data[.,col_year].<=1992);
```

I rewrite this in matlab with

```
x7992 = data(data(:,col_coh)==0 & data(:,col_year)<=1992);
```

`col_coh，col_year` are predefined column number.

However, rather than give me a sub-matrix, the above line of code only give me a single row (23166-by-1),it's not what I want (and not the real result base on this condition).So how to fix it? thank you.

--- Update -----

The `data` matrix is like (I omit other columns because only first 3 cols are relevant to selection), the first column is id for individuals

```
1  1979  0
1  1980  0
1  1981  1
1  1982  0
1  1983  1
2  1990  0
2  1991  0
2  1992  0
2  1993  1
3  1985  0
3  1986  0
3  1987  0
```

Based on the conditions, what I want is a submatrix from data, which excludes those rows with value>1992 in the second column and value=1 in the third one

Comment: Give an example of `data` matrix and the expected output

Comment: Hi,@Sardar_Usama, I add some further details of my data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example that you have given, the following will do this:

```
data(data(:,2)<=1992 & data(:,3)~=1,:)
```

which gives this output:

```
       1   1979   0
       1   1980   0
       1   1982   0
       2   1990   0
       2   1991   0
       2   1992   0
       3   1985   0
       3   1986   0
       3   1987   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get a single column vector as output since your condition vector is returned as a single 23166x1 vector.

To get the entire row of values you need to add a [colon](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/) as a second argument.
I've splitted the example in two lines to make more readable.

```
condIdx = data(:,col_coh)==0 & data(:,col_year)<=1992;
x7992 = data( condIdx, :);
```

If you want specific columns in your result matrix, just put the column number in a vector instead of the colon operator.

```
colsInResult = [1 2 3];
x7992 = data( condIdx, colsInResult);
```